# Intellij, prevent wrap of lines when tab window is narrow

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

Is there a way to prevent Intellij from wrapping lines when the code line exceeds the window width?

Right now it is wrapping my code when in split mode ( vertical ) but this doesn't help me navigate the code any easier. If I need to scroll right I can do that myself.

How can I prevent this wrapping from occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the below comment, **uncheck `Use soft wrap in editor` is the solution.**
[image]

Comment: Try splitting your editor into two panes instead. Then minimize one, it will wrap your lines into something very readable and recognizable, something like this: http://s7.postimg.org/wdoq2xhiz/Screenshot_from_2015_05_08_16_36_26.png

Comment: It is unchecked here. Perhaps there is a bug with this option. Have you tried without? Your code is wrapping in the picture above.

Comment: I just try `uncheck`, It works. It will prevent auto wrap. What is your version, operating system? I use lastest IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2 and Windows x64 8.1 .

Comment: I had it unchecked. I checked it, restarted, then unchecked it again, and now it works. There must have been a bug in Intellij. I'll accept your answer since you were quick enough to and helped debug the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I have to repeat this everytime I restart intellij. Check it, then uncheck it. Very stable!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have *Soft Wraps* enabled? To disable it go to the *Editor > General > use soft wraps in the editor* option in the settings.

Comment: Nope, it's not on, but it's certainly behaving as soft wraps should behave. See http://s7.postimg.org/wdoq2xhiz/Screenshot_from_2015_05_08_16_36_26.png

Comment: Can you try splitting into vertical windows and resize one to become smaller?

Answer (score 0):

From Settings-> Project Settings -> Wrapping and Braces at Wrapping Options panel, check "Ensure right margin is not exceeded" as you requested.

For more information, see 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/wrapping-and-braces.html

Comment: Nope, that only is to ensure my margin is not exceeded. I do not want that. I want the editor not to wrap my code when the tab window gets to small to fit. It's not even margin related. Actually, I don't remember this being a problem before I updated to the latest Intellij 14 141.173 version, but I could be wrong. Haven't worked with narrow windows in a while.